# Typescript and React - Intellisense finds problem with passing an interface as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass props into a component in typescript. I've created a `LobbyProps` interface and my component has it as an argument. If I try passing the props to `LobbyPage`, I get a warning in WebStorm. From what I can tell it is being correctly passed through when I run the application.

> TS2322: Type '{ clientSocket: Socket; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.   
> Property 'clientSocket' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

**App.tsx (Simplified)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Socket} from "socket.io";
import {LobbyPage, LobbyProps} from "/imports/ui/lobby/LobbyPage";

export class App extends React.Component {

    socket: Socket;

    constructor(props: Object) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};

        const io = require("socket.io-client")
        this.socket = io.connect("http://localhost:9999/")
    
    }

    render() {

        return <div>
            {/* The warning mentioned above is on the clientSocket variable here*/}
            <LobbyPage clientSocket={this.socket}/> 
        </div>
    }
}
```

**LobbyPage.tsx (Simplified)**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Socket} from "socket.io";

export interface LobbyProps {
    clientSocket: Socket
}

export class LobbyPage extends Component {
    constructor(lobbyProps: LobbyProps) {
        super(lobbyProps);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
            <button onClick={() => this.createSession()}>Create Chess Session</button>
        </div>
    }


    private createSession(): void {
        this.props.clientSocket.emit("create-session");
        console.log("Creating session") // This is successful with no errors during runtime
    }
}
```

From what I can tell this has been done in the same way as the tutorials I've followed.

What is the correct method of passing the props with an interface?

Comment: Have you tried `class LobbyPage extends Component<LobbyProps>`?

Comment: @ArmanCharan is correct. I think react components are expecting the type of props that we are passing. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pkf1ao

Comment: @ArmanCharan You're right. If you'd like to answer the question I'll accept it thanks! I didn't realise the type could be specified for the component.

Comment: For additional context, the type definition for `React.Component` accepts generic parameters, `<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any>`, where `P` is the type of `this.props`, `S` is the type of `this.state`, and `SS` is the type of the snapshot parameter passed to `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class LobbyPage extends Component<LobbyProps>` should work.

For additional context, the type definition for `React.Component` accepts generic parameters, `<P = {}, S = {}, SS = any>`, where `P` is the type of this.props, `S` is the type of this.state, and `SS` is the type of the snapshot parameter passed to `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I just realised the same for the state too. Thank you for the help!